# Find the work done by the force F in moving a particle.

Tags: vectors

F = (2x + y )i + ( 4y - x )j,  c is taken once round the triangle with vertices at (2,2) , (4,2) & (4,4) taken counter clockwise.

Comment: hi welcome to stack exchange, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you know the divergence theorem? What have you tried? What are you confused about? This isn't the type of site where you can post something that's obviously a homework question without showing that you've put some effort into the problem.